# Take no action if optional reference is deleted

Tags: node.js, sqlite, prisma

I am using Node.js and Prisma having a table `Main` that has two relations to other tables that correspond to another element (`productId` and `storageId`). If one of the elements is deleted from referenced tables the foreign key in `Main` should be set to null. The table schema:

```
model Main {
  id             String          @id @default(uuid())
  action         String
  StorageProduct StorageProduct? @relation(fields: [productId, storageId], references: [productId, lagerfachId], onDelete: NoAction)
  amount         Int
  Product        Product?        @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id], onDelete: SetNull)
  productId      String?
  Storage        Storage?        @relation(fields: [storageId], references: [id], onDelete: SetNull)
  storageId      String?
}
```

Another table `StorageProduct` contains additional information if there is a combination of the `storageId` and the `productId`. As this is an optional connection the reference is also optional. If a record is deleted from `StorageProduct` I have to define a delete action in table `Main`. But as the `productId` and `storageId` still exists even if the record in table `StorageProduct` is deleted there should be no action executed in table `Main` if a delete happens from `StorageProduct`.

[Delete actions that can be defined](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/referential-actions#how-to-use-referential-actions). How SQLite [defines `NoAction`](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions).

If I try to delete the `LagerProduct` element I receive the error "foreign key constraint failed". Is there no way to achieve this? Deleting the `StorageProduct` reference would be an option but then I would have to fetch it in a separate query.